# Faster alternative to for loops in R?

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to calculate a transition probability (without Markov assumption), which require calculating this nested integration,  [image: nested integral]

Note that the **integrals** can be replace by **summations** in my case. Here is a toy example code I am using to calculate this,

```
# simulate some data
set.seed(99)
data<-data.frame(time=seq(0,7,0.1),
             S_D=seq(1,0.95,length.out = 71),
             lam12=sample(c(0,0.1,0.12,0.15,0.17),size = 71,replace = TRUE),
             lam23=sample(c(0,0.05,0.1,0.08,0.12),size = 71,replace = TRUE),
             lam24=sample(c(0,0.02,0.05,0.06,0.08),size = 71,replace = TRUE))

prob_123<-c() # initializing a NULL vector
end<-nrow(data)

for (j in 2: end)
{
  # j indicates u in the expresstion
  # k indicates v in the expression
  prob_123k<-0
  for (k in (j+1):end)
  {
    if (k==(j+1)){  
      prob_123k<-prob_123k+data$S_D[j-1]*data$lam12[j]*data$lam12[k-j]
    }
    if (k>(j+1)){ 
  
      prob_123k<-prob_123k+data$S_D[j-1]*data$lam12[j]*prod(1-(data$lam12[1:(k-j-1)]+data$lam24[1:(k-j-1)]))*(data$lam12[k-j])
   }
  }
  prob_123[j-1]<-prob_123k
}

sum(prob_123)  # result = 5.631623
```

In the code, `S_D` corresponds to expression `exp{-(\Lambda_12(u)+\Lambda_13(u)+\Lambda_14(u))}` and `prod(1-(...))` corresponds to expression `exp{-(\Lambda_23(v-u)+\Lambda_24(v-u))}`. My original dataset is much bigger than this and it takes a long time calculate the nested for loops. Can anyone please suggest any faster alternatives? Thank you so much.

Comment: @Axeman: apologies for the mistake. I edited the code.

Comment: Small improvement: be sure to pre-allocate a result vector the same size (and type, ideally) as your results (i.e., `prob_123<- vector("numeric", nrow(data))`). It will make a difference as the loop grows. As-is, R copies `prob_123` each time it adds a value to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `cumprod` and `sum` to get the loops faster.

Encapsulating your for-loop into a function `f`:

```
f <- function(data) {
  end <- nrow(data)
  prob_123 <- vector("numeric", end) # initializing a NULL vector
  for (j in 2:end) {
    # j indicates u in the expresstion
    # k indicates v in the expression
    prob_123k <- 0
    for (k in (j + 1):end) {
      
      if (k == (j + 1)) {  
        prob_123k <- prob_123k + data$S_D[j - 1] * data$lam12[j] * data$lam12[k - j]
      }
      if (k > (j + 1)) { 
        prob_123k <- prob_123k + data$S_D[j - 1] * data$lam12[j] * data$lam12[k - j] *
          prod(1 - (data$lam12[1:(k - j - 1)] + data$lam24[1:(k - j - 1)]))
      }
    }
    prob_123[j - 1] <- prob_123k
  }
  
  sum(prob_123)    
}

f(data)
5.631623
```

We note that there's an unnecessary re-computation of the running product - it can be computed once and then indexed appropriately. Rewriting the function as follows:

```
ff <- function(data) {
  end <- nrow(data)
  prob_123 <- vector("numeric", end) # initializing a NULL vector
  p <- cumprod(1 - (data$lam12 + data$lam24))
  for (j in 2:end) {
    # j indicates u in the expresstion
    # k indicates v in the expression
    if (j + 1 <= end) {
      prob_123k <- data$S_D[j - 1] * data$lam12[j] * data$lam12[(j + 1):end - j] * 
        c(p[1], p[1:(end - j - 1)])
    }
    prob_123[j - 1] <- sum(prob_123k) + # Equivalent to the k > j + 1 part
      data$S_D[j - 1] * data$lam12[j] * data$lam12[j + 1 - j] # Equivalent to k = j + 1 part
  }
  
  sum(prob_123)    
}

identical(f(data), ff(data))
TRUE
```

We can then use the `microbenchmark` package to see if there's an improvement:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f(data), ff(data))
Unit: microseconds
     expr      min       lq     mean   median        uq       max neval
  f(data) 8853.501 9020.902 10118.14 9410.351 10416.201 14392.401   100
 ff(data)  344.701  356.401   373.86  367.301   384.701   466.401   100
```

The function `ff` is about 30x faster on average.

I'm sure code jockeys can optimise this even more, by getting rid of `j` for-loop, perhaps?

Comment: thanks for the pointing out the unnecessary computation. However, the functions ```f``` and ```ff``` are not giving me identical results. I like the suggestion regarding the ```cumprod```. I will incorporate it.

Comment: Interesting that you're getting different results for `f` and `ff`. For me, they're the same! I'm using R4.0.2.